# subtraction is not working with velocity template

Tags: velocity

I have this code in velocity html

```
<html>



#set ($Total1 = 0.0)
#set ($Total2 = 3.0)
#set ($Total3 = $Total2 -$Total1)
$Total3

</html>
```

The $Total3 is not getting displayed. In fact the subtraction is not working. Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Make sure you are using a modern version. Ancient Velocity versions only supported integer math.

Answer (score 12):

I just tried that example in Velocity 1.6 and it worked fine.

Two possible things that might be causing problems.

(1) Your example is not copied correctly.  If a dash is next to an identifier, it becomes part of the identifier.  So this example would fail, since the "-" sign is actually part of the Total2 identifier.

```
#set ($Total3 = $Total2- $Total1)
```

(2) You are using a very old version of Velocity.  Floating point numbers were legal syntax beginning with Velocity 1.5.  (The current version is 1.7).  Before that point, integers were the only number type allowed.

Comment: Option 1 was on point for me. Very tricky to spot! I was using Integers in my case and a "simple" counter decrease was failing with mysterious message: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "-1" 

So beware of this and "space out" the other term as suggested in answer, even for integers when assigning