# Accessing ArrayList by index using Velocity Templates

Tags: java, arraylist, velocity

I'm passing in a HashMap with a String mapping to an ArrayList.
The map contains two entries, which are ArrayLists of the same length, and I want them aligned horizontally, so I figured a foreach-range loop would work better than a foreach loop on the entries individually.

I have:

```
#foreach($i in [1..$entry1.size()])
    <li>
        <h3>$entry1.get($i-1)</h3>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="$entry2.get($i-1)" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </li>
#end
```

Velocity just prints $entry1.get($i-1) and takes $entry2.get($i-1) literally $entry1.size() times, instead of injecting the values from the corresponding ArrayList indices.

The Velocity [Documentation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#index-notation) says:

> NOTE: For the ArrayList example the elements defined with the [..] operator are accessible using the methods defined in the ArrayList class. So, for example, you could access the first element above using $monkey.Say.get(0).

And the example was:

```
#set( $monkey.Say = ["Not", $my, "fault"] ) ## ArrayList
```

Am I accessing the ArrayList correctly?

Comment: I think you need to put spaces before and after the dash, for subtraction to work. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448108/subtraction-is-not-working-with-velocity-template).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that velocity isn't evaluating expression inside `get()` method at `$entry1.get($i-1)`.

Try something like this :

```
#foreach($i in [1..$entry1.size()])
    #set($index = $i - 1)
    <li>
        <h3>$entry1.get($index)</h3>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="$entry2.get($index)" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </li>
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm still unsure as to what was wrong with my code above...
This was my work around though:

```
#foreach( $title in $entry1 )
  <li>
    <h3>$title</h3>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="$entry2.get($foreach.index)" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </li>
#end
```

Hope it helps anyone who may run across a similar problem in the future.
Would still like to know what was wrong with my initial code though!