# Addition in velocity template engine

Tags: velocity

I have to increment a number in velocity template engine.

```
#set ($newIndex = $oldIndex+ 1)
 $newIndex
```

but i am getting incorrect result e.g if value of $oldIndex is 1 then i am getting 11 instead of 2

Comment: How `oldIndex` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `oldIndex` defined as a number, it seems similar to [substraction not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448108/subtraction-is-not-working-with-velocity-template)

> Your example is not copied correctly. If a dash is next to an identifier, it becomes part of the identifier. So this example would fail, since the "-" sign is actually part of the Total2 identifier.

Add space after variable name:

```
#set ($newIndex = $oldIndex + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with spaces in this case, but rather with the initial content of $oldIndex.

The following template:

```
#set ($i = '1')
#set ($i = $i + 1)
$i.class.name / $i

#set ($j = 1)
#set ($j = $j + 1)
$j.class.name / $j
```

displays:

```
11 / java.lang.String

2 / java.lang.Integer
```

So you need to convert `$oldIndex` to a number, but the way to do it depends of the tools you have available in your context to do so (if you can't put `$oldIndex` as a number in the context in the first place). You would typically do something like `#set ($oldIndex = $number.toNumber($oldIndex))` if you have the NumberTool present in your context, for instance.

There's a method that will probably work in all environments:

```
#set ($dummy = 1)                            ## creates an Integer variable
#set ($oldIndex = $dummy.valueOf($oldIndex)) ## uses Integer.valueOf() method
```

And that's it, `$oldIndex` contains an integer! Please note that the `Integer.valueOf()` method may throw a `NumberFormatException` if given something else than a number representation.